# Maximal number of fixed size ellipsis in a certain area

Tags: opencv, ellipse

I'm looking for code to find the maximal amount of fixed size ellipses in a certain area. I have hand drawn arbitrary shapes and I want to inscribe several amount of ellipses such that the cover the most amount of pixels of that area. Any hint for some code or mathematical keyword to find (efficient) solutions for such a problem?
Thanks!
Durin

Comment: I would love to see what you have tried so far, meanwhile check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785419/detection-of-coins-and-fit-ellipses-on-an-image) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416117/simple-object-detection-using-opencv-and-machine-learning/6416361#6416361) and [this](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/how-can-we-find-ellipse-using-open-cv-in-an-image-td4284950.html).

Comment: maximal inscribed ellipses, ellipse maximization problem ... but I'm not interested in a maximal ellipse more in a maximal amount of ellipses inside an arbitrary shape

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307263/ellipse-detection-using-hough-transform) is also interesting.

Comment: Hough transformation is rather slow and looks for every possible ellipse. I guess some approach that makes use of the border of the shape will be much faster?

Comment: I think it could be. On this subject, I find [this thread](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/1992) interesting (there are a lot of msgs in there, take your time): [Another relative simple way to detect ellipses in binary images is
using Moments](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/2014)

Comment: Do you want to detect ellipses within the image or find a way to stick the maximum number of ellipses into a given region?  I think the latter is what you are asking.  If so, this isn't really an OpenCV issue (except to find the bounding region), but more a mathematical/algorithm issue.  The general class of problems is called "packing problems" or "packing algorithms" and is well-studied. See, e.g., [packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem) and [this paper](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~garyd/Publications/Delaney_2005_PhilMag_Random_Packing_Ellipses.pdf).