# How to detect malformed-ellipse-alike objects?

Tags: image-processing, filter, classification, noise, hough-transform

I need to process a stack of ultrasonic images, where there is mostly a lot of noise to see, but I need to extract specific objects that look for example like this:

[image]

Here is an example from Wikipedia of  pretty nice formed object [image]

But I'm not sure how to get the whole region.

**What I did:**

I already tried with *mean* & *median* filters to achieve a binary image in the end, which then is processed with the *union-find*-method to create regions. Unfortunately this leads to vague results. And it seems like the difference of the edge pixels aren't high enough to get a clean *sobel*-image (for trying to define the margins).

**What I believe could work**

On a different project I was working with the hough-algorithm to detect a (very clean shaped) ball in a picture. I heard this method can be applied for lines and thus for curves too. But would I be able to detect a region like this ? And if so, how would it be? is it multiple hough-detection for just one area? Since I need to process in real time I'm afraid this would exceed the processing frame (or wouldn't it?)

**My question**

Has anyone an idea how to easily detect such objects ? Would it be possible to apply hough under real-time conditions, on an *ordinary* (not an high end) computer too?

Thanks for any advises!
Kind Regards

Comment: if you are looking for solution using hough transform this post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307263/ellipse-detection-using-hough-transform

Comment: if you want the result using less complex way, please post an image without annotation so we can try some algorithms. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

For the preprocessing part, here is what I've tried:

```
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.Read("/Users/FiReTiTi/Desktop/ACvtI.jpg") ;

ASFilterCloseOpen asfco = new ASFilterCloseOpen() ;
Median median = new Median() ;

BufferedImage resmed = median.Filter(im, new StructuringElement(3, StructuringElement.DISK), nbCPU) ;
BufferedImage resco = asfco.Filter(resmed, se, nbCPU) ;
```

It's just a median filter (size 3) followed by an alternate sequential filter starting with a closing and of size 5. It seems to give a good separation of the different regions.

Here is [the result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/MalformedEllipse.png).