# Do you have a good idea in extracting the positions of feature points

Tags: python, opencv

I have been doing a an assignment about computer vision on python using opencv-3.2.
Now I am in trouble extracting the accurate positions of feature points.
Image is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYojC.jpg).

Binary image is like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZRci.jpg).

I have to know the accurate positions of ellipses in plate.

I try to use cv2.findContours,but I find it difficult to obtain a satisfactory result. I am thinking about using cv2.findContours after selecting a  piece of area which can reduce the impact of noise. However, considering the numbers of pics, that is hard to achieve.
So I am looking for a better idea.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html)

Comment: ok that seem to work,I will try it tomorrow. time for bed, thx anyway!

Comment: [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html) is for python

Comment: @lelle Ofcourse, that is what you've asked for..... isn't it?

Comment: Don't understand the point of your comment @lelle

Comment: in fact I am trying [this](http://www2.dis.ulpgc.es/~lalvarez/research/calibracion_elipse.pdf)     ellipse detection based on Hough Transform

Comment: The paper you added in the comment mentions Hough circle detection right? I have put a link for the same.

Comment: @RickM. yes, but I need to detect  ellipse, Hough circle detection is not suitable for this situation

Comment: How do you know it isn't suitable? Have you tried it? I have added an answer.

Comment: @RickM. yean, I have tried it, but no result come out. Because those circles become ellipses after the projection, the standard circle detection does not work

Comment: Did you try from my answer?[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307263/ellipse-detection-using-hough-transform)

Comment: @RickM. great! your answer help me a lot : ) thx!

Comment: @lelle If it did, kindly accept it for future visitors! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments, there are two possible approaches for achieving this:

**Approach 1** : *SimpleBlobDetector*

This detector is tuned to detect circular blobs. 
Code for C++

```
 Mat image = imread("image.jpg");
 Ptr<FeatureDetector> blobsDetector = FeatureDetector::create("SimpleBlob");
 vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
 blobsDetector->detect(image, keypoints);
 // Drawing 
 Mat drawImage = image.clone();
 for (size_t i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); ++i){
   circle(drawImage, keypoints[i].pt, 4, Scalar(255, 0, 255), -1); }
 imwrite("result.png", drawImage);`
```

**Approach 2**: As the OP said contour detection. [*Reference*](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_attic/blob/master/opencv/samples/cpp/fitellipse.cpp)
The contours would probably need to be filtered for the referenced images. You could do:

1. Create two binary images of zero pixel value, one is to draw contours and another is for drawing ellipse.
2. Scan through each contour and draw it in the binary image, at the same time draw the ellipse to other binary for corresponding contour. For both cases, use `CV_FILLED` as thickness parameter.
3. Now perform `bitwise_xor` between the two binary images and count the number of non-zero pixels on the result. If the result is close to zero, the contour is identical to an ellipse, otherwise not.
4. Repeat for every contour.

PS. I still think HoughTransform would work but which method to use is upto you to decide. 
Hope it helps!