# How to detect an ellipse in a wheel with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have the image of a wheel and I want to detect the ellipse that maps to this wheel (or the inner circle of the wheel) with OpenCV (for pose estimation of the vehicle/wheel).

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Does anyone know how to do this?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The resulting image should look like this (or somewhat like this - I need to retrieve a few points that go through the ellispe). Please note, the result should be an ellipse, not a circle, because the wheel can be in perspective/in distortion, if looked at from the side.

So far I experimented with Contour (and identifying the largest contour area), canny, and color thresholding, I am able to identify the inner ellipse of the wheel on most of my test images (success!). This "inner ellipse" is part of the largest contour, however it contains other points as well that I don't need.

See image:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

The final question is, how to derive a few points of this inner circle/ellipse (and get rid of the other garbage) such that I can calculate the ellipse parameters?

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my code so far:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import skimage.filters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

from skimage import data, color, img_as_ubyte
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.transform import hough_ellipse
from skimage.draw import ellipse_perimeter

# get filename and sigma value from command line
filename0 = 'back_wheel.png'
filename1 = "backwheel1.png"
filename2 = "backwheel2.png"
filename3 = "backwheel3.png"
filename4 = "frontwheel1.png"
filename5 = "frontwheel2.png"

def getWheel0(filename):

    image_rgb_orig = cv2.imread(filename)
    image_rgb = image_rgb_orig.copy()

    print('Original Dimensions : ',image_rgb.shape)

    width = 350
    height = (int)(width * image_rgb.shape[0]/image_rgb.shape[1])
    dim = (width, height)


    image_rgb = cv2.resize(image_rgb, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(image_gray)
    #edges = cv2.Canny(image_gray, 150, 200)

    norm_image = cv2.normalize(equ, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

    #--- First obtain the threshold using the greyscale image ---
    ret,th = cv2.threshold(norm_image, 50, 100, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)

    #--- Find all the contours in the binary image ---
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th,2,1)
    #contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1)
    cnt = contours
    big_contour = []
    max = 0
    for i in cnt:
      area = cv2.contourArea(i) #--- find the contour having biggest area ---
      if(area > max):
        max = area
        big_contour = i 

    result = cv2.drawContours(image_rgb, big_contour, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

    fig2, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=1, figsize=(8, 4), sharex=True,
                                    sharey=True)

    ax1.set_title('Original picture')
    ax1.imshow(image_rgb_orig)

    ax2.set_title('Threshhold')
    ax2.imshow(th)

    ax3.set_title('Contour')
    ax3.imshow(result)

    plt.show()

getWheel0(filename0)
getWheel0(filename1)
getWheel0(filename2)
getWheel0(filename3)
getWheel0(filename4)
getWheel0(filename5)
```

running it with 
"python tire.py"

Comment: which ellipse do you mean? The yellow disturbed one?

Comment: I would like to know the ellipse that goes through the tire. It is mostly close to a circle, however when seen from the side, it would be an ellipse. The reason I want to know the ellipse that goes through the wheel, is because from this ellise, I can estimate the pose of the vehicle.

Comment: so basically the inner part of the tire?

Comment: Yes exactly. The inner part of the tire would be it.

Comment: I would try RANSAC based methods.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of locating circle on an image is well-known and is already solved.

Use Hough circle transform.
It's a basic functionality of OpenCV lib to: [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html).

Generalized Hough transform may be used to detect ellipses. But you will need to code it yourself since, some reasonable ideas provided in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307263/ellipse-detection-using-hough-transform). You need accumulator with more dimensions (5) that in case of line (2) or circle (3) detection but it shouldn't be a problem.

It also look like canny gives good edges on your image. You can try following:

1. For connected contours (above some minimal length) find the pair of most far points (big axis) and pair of most close points orthogonal to big axis.
2. Connecting pairs of points gives ellipse axes (with ellipse center in cross point). Compute ellipse parameters.
3. Check other contour's point whether they match computed ellipse (with some small shift allowed). If so contours is an ellipse, otherwise it is not.

Both of this solutions might not work good for ovals and ellips-like contours with asymmetrical axes.

Comment: Hough circle transform works only for circles. I need the same for ellises.

Comment: It's my miss. Some of your test images looked like circles, that's what tricked me.

Comment: Hello, I edited my question. Identifying the inner ellipse seems to be fine, now I need to separate the good points from the largest contour to identify some points of the ellipse. Perhaps you have an idea. Many thanks!

Comment: You can do following:
split contours point into top and bottom half -> for each points pair (one top, one bottom) half of the dist between them is a possible radius, vote for it (you can take in account only outer contour points and omit close points to reduce computational cost) -> most commonly voted radius is what you may need, take the average if several close radius values have close score -> radius * 2 value should be close to contour's bounding box height.
You can do the same for left and right contour's half, to find another axis.

Comment: Sure the voting scheme can be more complicated, e.g. RANSAC like proposed in comments to your question.

Comment: Sounds good and makes perfectly sense. I'll try this asap and give feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your posts. These were very helpful to come close to an answer. I finally end up doing the following:

grayscale
normalize
findContours

Then on the contours, I do cornerHarris, which returns a Mat of the size of the image with a corner value for each pixel of the contours.

I normalize the values of the cornerHarries Mat to values between 0 and 255.
0 are straight lines (no corners), and I then set every value below 2 (straight lines) and any value above 20 to 255, such that only "soft curves" remain in the Mat.

After this step I loop through the Mat and remove all values that =255 or that are in close distance to the points that are 255.

The result is (at least for this one test image) that only a part of the ellipse points remain, and these are enough for findEllipse to return the correct ellipse.